# Mapbox supportMapFragment / mapView is black on Android versions lower than 8

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I am using mapView and a SupportMapFragment to display the map in a fragment. On newer Android versions (I tested 8 and 9 on different devices) the map displays without any problem. However, on older Android versions (I tested 6 and 7) the map is showing a black screen (see [black screen pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMmk9.png)). The maps seems to work correctly though. I can click on it, routes are properly calculated an I can start navigation. So did I initialize the mapView / mapFragment wrong? How can I remove the black screen and get the mapView working on older Android versions?

I tried to initialize the mapView differently, but nothing seemed to do the trick. The map remains black. Since there is also no console output, regarding the black screen, I do not know how to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The MainActivity.java:

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

(...)

// Create supportMapFragment
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            // Create fragment
            final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Build mapboxMap
            MapboxMapOptions options = new MapboxMapOptions();
            options.camera(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(-52.6885, -70.1395))
                    .zoom(9)
                    .build());

            // Create map fragment
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);

            // Add map fragment to parent container
            transaction.add(R.id.container2, mapFragment, "com.mapbox.map");
            transaction.commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        } else {
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("com.mapbox.map");
        }

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

                MainActivity.this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
                mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);

(...)

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapFragment.onStart();
    }

// etc.
(...)
```

Part of the activity_main.xml containing the mapView and the container2 for the mapFragment:

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/mapView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
(...)
```

I expect the mapView/fragment to show properly not only in newer Android versions, but also in older Android versions.

Comment: can someone help me?

Comment: add this app:mapbox_renderTextureMode